# How many possible passwords are there?

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Hi. Does some one know the answer?

Comment: Yes, someone knows the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Total number of ways of making $4$ digits long password (unique digits) = $10P_4 = 5040$.(Permutation of $4$ selected digits out of $10$)
This includes both increasing and decreasing sequence.
Number of increasing sequence number = $10C_4$ (You select $4$ digits out of $10$ and arrange in only one way i.e. increasing). Similarly number of decreasing sequence numbers = $10C_4 = 210$.
So if we subtract these two cases from total number of cases, we get the required number of ways = $5040-(210+210) = 4620$.

Comment: +1, very nice answer. Too bad that OP hasn't shown any effort in the question, so it will be closed along with it.